# GIT: How to pull changes from branch after a reverted merge

Tags: git, github, merge, git-pull, git-revert

I hope the title is not very confusing.

History (aka What I did wrong):

Let's say there are two branches, master and feature. Feature is a branch where I keep a longer feature project  and from time to time I use git pull origin master on that branch to stay updated with changes in main code.

I accidentally merged and pushed feature into master.

It was nowhere near ready, so I tried to revert it. I tried following: http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#pushed_new_merge
But I guess I did it wrong. I used:
git revert 
then commited the revert and pushed it. Problem seemed solved - the feature changes where no longer on master.

Now the problem is that when I try to use git pull origin master on feature branch it keeps deleting my files and reverting all changes, as it is merging with the revert-commit. The head of master is way past that revert and I need to pull the changes from newer commits to continue with feature branch.

I've googled the topic and the most promising answer is this: 
https://metlos.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/git-merging-after-a-revert/
but here the merge goes other way than I want to (feature to master, i need master to feature).

I am thinking of creating clone branch of master, then applying the instructions from the link on that branch so I can get the results I need, but I am afraid it's a temporary solution I would need to apply anytime I want to pull from master.

I tried best for this story not to be chaotic, If something is not understandable I will clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not pushed master branch to a team/public repository and you have no commit after the pull on master, you may do

```
git reset --hard **the-commit-before-pulling-feature-branch**
```

on the *master* branch. This will effectively wipe out the mistake from history and gives a clean history.

otherwise, (i.e. if you have already pushed master to a repo or done more commits on master), you may do

```
git revert **the-revert-commit**
```

on the *feature* branch after pulling the master, effectively reverting the revert commit.

Comment: I had it pushed and new commits were already made. Your solution worked like a charm, At first I got a 'could not revert' error, but it was just one file that needed manual merging. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: How to revert a "revert of merge commit" when pulling master branch to my feature branch? It expects some parent node/branch. Could you please also add this part in your answer?